# How to post code in this website?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone please tell me how to post code in this site? whenever i am trying to post code here I am getting some format error. It is saying like leave 4 lines or something like that.I am not getting it. Please help me. I am having some code problem which I want to post.

Comment: It is stunning how regularly we get this question migrated to Meta.

Answer (score 0):

the arrow shows it...

you simply MARK your code and than click this button and than post it :)

[image: how to post code]

Comment: It took me quite a while to notice that arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave four spaces before each line of code, it will appear in code format. If you're pasting a large amount of code, adding for spaces before each line is a bit of a pain: in that case, you can paste the code, highlight the selection, and click the button `{}` to automatically insert the spaces.

For a small amount of code inline, as opposed to a code block, you can use the ` key before and after to mark it as code. Again, the `{}` button will also do this for you.